# Specify constructor params for class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a ES6 class like this in a classic ES6 npm package:

```
class Document {
  /**
   *
   * @param {Object} options
   * @param {String} [options.title]
   * @param {String} [options.type]
   * @param {String} [options.detail]
   * @param {String} [options.instance]
   * @param {Number} [options.status]
   * @param {Extension} [extension]
   */
  constructor (options, extension) { // some implementation ... }
}
```

Now I want to provide some TypeScript typings for that class.

I tried this but `options` and `extension` are ignored by e.g. WebStorm or VS Code.

```
declare module "myModule" {

    class Document implements IDocument {
        constructor(options: IDocumentOptions, extension: IExtension)

        detail: string;
        extension: IExtension;
        instance: string;
        status: number;
        title: string;
        type: string;
    }

    interface IDocument {
        title: string,
        type: string,
        detail?: string,
        instance?: string,
        status: number,
        extension?: IExtension
    }

    interface IDocumentOptions {
        title: string,
        type: string,
        detail?: string,
        instance?: string,
        status: number,
        extension?: IExtension
    }

    interface IExtension {

    }

    const _: {
        Document: Document
    }


    export = _;

    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean with "ignored" ? If you compile with the command-line compiler does it work there ? Can you add your definitions of `IDocumentOptions` and `IExtension` ?

Comment: "Ignored" means they're not suggested as params for the ctor when trying to create an instance of `Document`. Even more when providing ctor params they're marked as not expected. I added `IDocumentOptions` and `IExtension` interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
type DocumentConstructor = 
    new (options: IDocumentOptions, extension: IExtension) => IDocument;
```

instead of

```
class Document implements IDocument {
    constructor(options: IDocumentOptions, extension: IExtension)

    detail: string;
    extension: IExtension;
    instance: string;
    status: number;
    title: string;
    type: string;
}
```

Comment: Uh, so `Document` is not a constructor but a callable function?  Or do you mean `type Document = new (options: IDocumentOptions, extension: IExtension) => IDocument;`?  And you might want to use the name `DocumentConstructor` instead of `Document`.  If you look at [the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L950-L970) that's the usual convention for distinguishing class constructor types from class instance types.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to overwrite a existed Document variable.

```
declare var Document: {
    prototype: Document;
    new(): Document;
};
```

Just you have to rename your class and add constructor implementation, finally it should works

Comment: I updated my question to show more details (=module declaration). Using `declare var` results in `TS1038: A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.` error.